# find annotated methods using clojure

Tags: class, reflection, clojure, annotations

How do I find all deprecated (or any other annotation) methods in a java class using clojure?

```
(filter #(.isAnnotationPresent % java.lang.Deprecated) (.getMethods (type java.util.Date)))
```

returns empty list because `(type java.util.Date)` returns `java.lang.Class`.  How do I get the correct class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave out the type:

```
(filter #(.isAnnotationPresent % java.lang.Deprecated) 
         (.getMethods java.util.Date))
```

now if you want to do it from string, then just do

```
(filter #(.isAnnotationPresent % java.lang.Deprecated) 
         (.getMethods (Class/forName "java.util.Date"))
```

type is used to get the type of a ***value***, now since symbols are resolved to actual classes, the type of the symbol is a java.lang.Class